# Rolling up rows into an average in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a data set like below, with a 1/0 column under "eligible" and a zipcode associated to each eligibility check.

```
"DATA_ELIGIBLE"         "B_ZIP5"
"0"                     "19958"
"1"                     "08846"
"0"                     "08846"
"0"                     "93546"
```

I would like to get an average eligibility score for each zipcode in SQL, i.e., if my data set were the above four rows, then my new data set would have 3 rows, with the score by `08846` equal to `0.5`. How can I do this? I'd also like to have another column that `COUNTs` the number of times a given zipcode appears. I could pull the dataset into Powerpivot and pivot table it out, but it is quite large (30MM rows) and that takes a while. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `data_eligible` is numeric, you can simply do:

```
select b_zip5, avg(data_eligible), count(*) as cnt
from table t
group by b_zip5;
```